# Assign string elements to variables

Tags: python, string

I have some strings with 3 elements, such as `'010','101'`... I'm trying to assign the elements of those strings to some variables, like a,b,c. I could do that through `a,b,c = "0 1 0".split()`. However, if there's no spacing in my string, how can I assign those values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it just like similar to the Tuple Unpacking, like

```py
a, b, c = '101'
```

Printing them will give you what you expect (in string format)

```py
print(a, b, c, type(a))
```

Outputs:

```
1 0 1 <class 'str'>
```

Tell me if its not working...

Comment: Thanks, that works! I wonder can I directly turn a,b,c into integers (i.e. 1,0,1), instead of doing `int(a)`?

Comment: @ZR- then you have to do loop through them and convert them into integer like `a, b, c = map(int, '101')`

Answer (score 1):

you can convert it to list

```
a,b,c=list('010')
```

Comment: simply add space and then split

Answer (score 1):

Use the index by listing it through the python `list()` function.

For example, Like this

```py
k = '010'

result = list(k)
print(result[0])
```

If there is no criteria to distinguish such as a gap, I think the `list()` is more comfortable than `.split()`.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way to split string if no space between, add space with join method and then split
example:

```
s = "101"

a,b,c = " ".join(s).split()
```

output:

```
#print(a, b, c)
1 0 1
```